# Prevent multiple pan gestures in custom UITableViewCells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a table view displaying custom table view cells. Each cell has a pan gesture recognizer to allow a view to be swiped left and right. Currently a user can swipe multiple cells simultaneously which is not desired behavior. I'd like to prevent multiple cells from being able to pan at any one time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Using `[self.myView setExclusiveTouch:YES];` will block the delivery of touch events to other views.